# C# connecting to sql server and error saying specified cast is not vaild is popping up

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing a program where I connect to a table in the sql server and get the coloumn values which are numbers.  When I try to do this an error saying specified cast is not valid.  Can anyone show me whats wrong with my program.  Below is my piece of code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string conn = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        conn= ("Data Source=Name\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Databse;User ID=user;Password=example");

        connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        try{

            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT coloum1,coloum2 FROM [dbo].[tb_table]");
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {

                Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader.GetInt(0), reader.GetInt(1));

            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }





    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show the values in the table.

Comment: this error is not related to sql server connection .

Comment: Are `coloum1` and `coloum2` both `int` values?

Comment: @Co.Aden what is the error related to then?

Comment: @colmde yes in an example is like this : "2009-03-16 00:00:00"  First date then time.

Comment: @Jack post the exact exception contents so we can answer. Where does it occur?

Comment: @Jack - I don't understand - dates / times are not the same as integers...

Comment: There's no `SqlDataReader.GetInt` method. The values you mention are *not* integer values, they are either datetime or string. Either you didn't post the faulting code or it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and tell me if it's work for you

```
 Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
```

you can also try

```
Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader["coloum1"].ToString(), reader["coloum2"].ToString());
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't work but a new error popped up saying "Unable to cast an object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String' ."

Comment: try the seconde suggstion

Comment: You need to use the *proper* `GetXYZ` method for the underlying type. Use `SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`

Comment: Thank you the second one worked very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try by change your line of code as I mentioned below,

```
Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", reader.GetDateTime(0), reader.GetDateTime(1));
```

You may follow this link for your referral [GetInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What's your database field ? Is it nvarchar or int ?